# Circular Image Cropping in Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

Trying to crop circular section from an image for Selecting profile photo( like G Plus).
Right now I am using PhotoChooserTask class where PixelWidth and PixelHeight is provided to draw a rectangular subview for cropping.

```
        PhotoChooserTask task = new PhotoChooserTask();
        task.PixelWidth = 100;
        task.PixelHeight = 100;
        task.Show();
```

How can I change this rectangular subview to circular one?
What parameters do I need to pass to PhotoChooserTask Object?

Comment: You need to mask the photo after you get it.  Perhaps using a writable bitmap?  Look into that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting the circular shape in the Photo chooser Task I recommend a much simpler way.

First get the image using the photo chooser task stream in jpeg format

Then do this

```
  WriteableBitmap mb = new WriteableBitmap(radius , radius)
  Ellipse circle = new Ellipse(your radius);
  circle.Background = new BitmapImage(yourImage);
  circle.render();
  mb.Invalidate();


  SaveJpeg( your ImageStream of Iso Storage)

 // To maintain transparency use SavePng() of Cimbalino.Phone.Toolkit
```